# Understanding the Difference Between 'e.g.' and 'For Example' in English Usage

Tags: word-usage, abbreviations

I often encounter the abbreviations "e.g." and the phrase "for example" in English texts and am curious about the specific differences in their usage. Are they completely interchangeable, or are there certain contexts where one is more appropriate than the other? Additionally, does the use of "e.g." versus "for example" change the tone or formality of a sentence?

Answer (score 6):

There is little or no difference in meaning, since "e.g." stands for the Latin *exempli gratia*, which basically just means "for example." It might make the tone slightly more academic because we're referencing Latin, but most people are familiar with it, and I regularly use it even in everyday speech.

I can see one difference: "for example" is sometimes put after the thing it references, like "We want a big dog—a Great Dane, for example" or "We have many outstanding students; Billy, for example, just won a prize." But doing this with "e.g." isn't really idiomatic; it usually precedes the phrase it relates to: "We want a big dog, e.g. a Great Dane."

Comment: You use e.g. in spoken sentences? I regularly type it, but I can't say I've heard anyone say it out loud.

Comment: @the-baby-is-you Yeahhhh, I might be a bad example because I'm pretty darn academic anyway. I don't actually go around saying "*exempli gratia*" out loud, but I come close.

Comment: I use e.g. in spoken sentences and i.e. as well. And AC and DC when I'm talking about electricity. And BC and AD and SPQR and INRI and AM and PM when I need to . We all do.